# What is the meaning of Jeremiah 49:12?

Tags: jeremiah

Jeremiah 49:12

> For thus says the LORD: “If those who did not deserve to drink the cup
>   must drink it, will you go unpunished? You shall not go unpunished,
>   but you must drink.

- Who are "those who did not deserve to drink the cup must drink it"?
- Who force those who did not deserve to drink the cup to drink it? (Force because there is the word "must")
- Who is this "you"?
- Why does this "you" get punished? (At first, I thought this "you" gets punished because he lets those who did not deserve to drink the cup to drink it, but there is the word "must drink it" so I think "you" gets punished for other reasons)

About the sentence "but you must drink". I think the drink here is the "wine of wrath".

Jeremiah 25:15

> Thus the LORD, the God of Israel, said to me: “Take from my hand this
>   cup of the wine of wrath, and make all the nations to whom I send you
>   drink it.

- So this "you" gets punished and gets to drink the "wine of wrath" is double punished?

Answer (score 1):

Read the rest of the chapter and the surrounding chapters.

The verse you highlight is part of a series of judgments God pronounces on different nations.

YLT Jeremiah 46:1-2, 13

> **That which hath been the word of Jehovah unto Jeremiah the prophet concerning the nations,**
>
> **For Egypt, concerning the force of Pharaoh-Necho king of Egypt, that hath been by the river Phrat, in Carchemish, that Nebuchadrezzar king of Babylon hath smitten,** in the fourth year of Jehoiakim son of Josiah king of Judah:
>
> ...
>
> **The word that Jehovah hath spoken unto Jeremiah the prophet concerning the coming in of Nebuchadrezzar king of Babylon**, to smite the land of Egypt:
>
> ...

YLT Jeremiah 47:1-2

> **That which hath been the word of Jehovah unto Jeremiah concerning the Philistines**, before Pharaoh smiteth Gaza:
>
> **'Thus said Jehovah**: Lo, waters are coming up from the north, And have been for an overflowing stream, And they overflow the land and its fulness, The city, and the inhabitants in it, And men have cried out, And howled hath every inhabitant of the land.
>
> ...

YLT Jeremiah 48:1

> **Concerning Moab: 'Thus said Jehovah of Hosts, God of Israel**: Wo unto Nebo, for it is spoiled, Put to shame, captured hath been Kiriathaim, Put to shame hath been the high tower, Yea, it hath been broken down.
>
> ...

YLT Jeremiah 49:1, 7, 23, 28, 34-35

> **Concerning the sons of Ammon: 'Thus said Jehovah**: Sons -- hath Israel none? heir -- hath he none? Wherefore hath Malcam possessed Gad? And his people in its cities have dwelt?
>
> ...
>
> **Concerning Edom: 'Thus said Jehovah of Hosts**: Is wisdom no more in Teman? Perished hath counsel from the intelligent? Vanished hath their wisdom?
>
> ...
>
> **Concerning Damascus**: Ashamed hath been Hamath and Arpad, For an evil report they have heard, They have been melted, in the sea is sorrow, To be quiet it is not able.
>
> ...
>
> **Concerning Kedar, and concerning the kingdoms of Hazor, that Nebuchadrezzar king of Babylon hath smitten: 'Thus said Jehovah:**
>
> ...
>
> **That which hath been the word of Jehovah unto Jeremiah the prophet concerning Elam, in the beginning of the reign of Zedekiah king of Judah, saying**:
>
> **'Thus said Jehovah of Hosts**: Lo, I am breaking the bow of Elam, The beginning of their might.
>
> ...

YLT Jeremiah 50:1

> **The word that Jehovah hath spoken concerning Babylon, concerning the land of the Chaldeans, by the hand of Jeremiah the prophet**:
>
> ...

Jeremiah 49:12 which your question highlights is in the section addressed to the inhabitants of Edom. This is reinforced in the next verse (verse 13) where it says:

> ...
>
> For, by Myself, I have sworn, An affirmation of Jehovah, That for a desolation, for a reproach, **For a waste, and for a reviling -- is Bozrah**, And all her cities are for wastes age-during.
>
> ...

Bozrah was the capital of the Edomites.

YLT Genesis 36:31-33

> ...
>
> And these are the kings who have **reigned in the land of Edom** before the reigning of a king over the sons of Israel.
>
> And Bela son of Beor reigneth in Edom, and the name of his city is Dinhabah;
>
> and Bela dieth, and reign in his stead doth Jobab son of Zerah **from Bozrah**
>
> ...

Those who are not sentenced to drink of the cup are not specified, but God uses whoever they are to drive home the point that even those who did not cause the trouble coming on the region have to deal with it and they could not escape it. Since the Edomites were in the center of all the trouble (because they were part the cause of the trouble) they would have to face the consequences -- even more so than those who were not responsible for it -- and if they thought they could avoid it they were very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand it now.

Jeremiah 49:12 reflects

- Jeremiah 25

> 15Thus the Lord, the God of Israel, said to me: “Take from my hand
>   this cup of the wine of wrath, and make all the nations to whom I send
>   you drink it.
>
> 27“Then you shall say to them, ‘Thus says the Lord of hosts, the God
>   of Israel: Drink, be drunk and vomit, fall and rise no more, because
>   of the sword that I am sending among you.’
>
> 28“And **if they refuse to accept the cup** from your hand to drink, then
>   you shall **say to them**, ‘Thus says the Lord of hosts: **You must drink!**
>   29For behold, I begin to work disaster at the city that is called by
>   my name, and shall you go unpunished? You shall not go unpunished, for
>   I am summoning a sword against all the inhabitants of the earth,
>   declares the Lord of hosts.’

So let's answer the questions

- Number 1: Who are "those who did not deserve to drink the cup must drink it"?

  - Answer: Jeremiah 25:15 "all the nations to whom I send you drink it". So the answer is: The nations who did not deserve to drink the cup in all the nations to whom The LORD send Jeremiah drink it.
- Number 2: Who force those who did not deserve to drink the cup to drink it? (Force because there is the word "must")

  - Answer: Jeremiah 25:28 "And if they refuse to accept the cup from your hand to drink, then you shall say to them, ‘Thus says the Lord of hosts: You must drink!". So the answer is The LORD.
- Number 3: Who is this "you"?

  - Answer: Jeremiah 49:7 "Concerning Edom.". So "you" is the Edom nation.
- Number 4: Why does this "you" (Edom) get punished?.

  - Answer: Jeremiah 25:29 "For behold, I begin to work disaster at the city that is called by my name, and shall you go unpunished? You shall not go unpunished, for I am summoning a sword against all the inhabitants of the earth, declares the Lord of hosts.’". Of course you need to read deeper to understand more reason.
- Number 4: So this "you" gets punished and gets to drink the "wine of wrath" is double punished?

  - Answer: No, "punish" & "drink" mean the same: punish. So not double punished.